# insert two lists to dict with different length

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists as following

`users_member = ['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6']`

`date = ['2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00']`

as far as I know ,I need to create dict from 2 lists so I will be able to save it as JSON file format in this way, I will have a reference if `dict[date]` was changed from previous script run if changed I will compare `dict[user_member]` value with JSON file and find the diff.

I run :

```
dict= dict(zip(users_members,cycle(date)))
```

output:

```
{'User1': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00', 'User2': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00', 'User3': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00', 'User4': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00', 'User5': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00', 'User6': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00'}
```

I think it should be look like , any idea how can I accomplished this ?

```
dict = {'date':'2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00'
'users_member': ['User1', 'User2','User3','User4','User5','User6']}
```

Comment: `{'users_member': users_member, 'date': date}` - this is a trivial dictionary construction and has nothing to do with the list lengths or there being lists at all. Or use `date[0]` instead of `date` to replicate the shown expected result exactly.

Comment: how do you suggest structure will be ? I need two lists in structure so I will be able to save as json file and easy to comparison?

Comment: simply `{'date': date[0], 'users_member': users_member}` should return that, but you should avoid naming variables `dict` because the next time you try calling, *`dict(....)`* it will raise an error

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
d = {'date': date[0], 'users_member': users_member}
print(d)

# Output
{'date': '2023-02-27 09:50:55+00:00',
 'users_member': ['User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4', 'User5', 'User6']}
```

Comment: wow ,now it so simple.is this structure will work if I need to save d as json file for compare if 'date' value was changed on next script run?

Comment: Yes you can use `json.load` and `json.dump` to read and save `d` as json file.